# How to check if a checkbox is enabled or not?

Tags: selenium, testng

How to ckeck the checkbox is enabled or not?
In selenium + Testng, in application im clicking on checkbox will be enabled, i need to verify whether the checkbox is enabled or not.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

There's a method **"isEnabled()", that checks whether a WebElement is enabled or not**. You can use the below code to check for that;

```
boolean enabled = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//xpath of the checkbox")).isEnabled();
```

**(** I have used xpath above but you can use id or cssselector for locating the element, too.**)**

**The above code will return 'true', if the concerned WebElement, i.e., in your case the checkbox, is enabled, else it will return 'false'**.

And, in case you want **to check whether the checkbox is checked/selected or not, you can use "isSelected()" method**, which you can use like this;

```
boolean checked = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//xpath of the checkbox")).isSelected();
```

**The above code will return 'true', if the concerned WebElement, i.e., in your case the checkbox, is checked, else it will return 'false'**.

---

Taking your code snippet in the comment, I have conjured up a method below:-

**This will return a string "Pass" if the checkbox is checked, and "Fail" if it isn't checked or in case any error comes up while executing this code.**

```
public static String isCheckBoxChecked(String objlocator, String elemName) {

        APP_LOGS.debug("Checking if the checkbox related to '"+elemName+"' is checked or not.");
        System.out.println("Checking if the checkbox related to '"+elemName+"' is checked or not.");

        try {

            findWebElement(objlocator);

            //Assuming the objLocator contains xpath
            if (driver.findElement(By.xpath(objlocator)).isSelected()) {
                System.out.println("Checkbox related to: '"+elemName+"' is checked.");
                APP_LOGS.debug("Checkbox related to: '"+elemName+"' is checked.");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Checkbox related to: '"+elemName+"' is not checked!!");
                APP_LOGS.debug("Checkbox related to: '"+elemName+"' is not checked!!");
                return "Fail" + ": Checkbox related to: '"+elemName+"' is not checked!!";
            }
        }
        catch (Throwable t) {
            System.out.println("Error while Checking if the checkbox related to '"+elemName+"' is checked or not. -" + t.getMessage());
            APP_LOGS.error("Error while Checking if the checkbox related to '"+elemName+"' is checked or not. -" + t.getMessage());
            return "Fail"+": Error while Checking if the checkbox related to '"+elemName+"' is checked or not. -" + t.getMessage();
        }

        return "Pass"+": Checkbox related to: '"+elemName+"' is checked.";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code. This will return a boolean value based on if check box is checked or not. Based on that you can either click on the checkbox. Happy coding.

```
boolean selected = element.isSelected();
        if(!selected)
        {
            element.click();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this if you :

```
bool flag = false;
        if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
            flag = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Checking
public void CheckingChkbox(WebElement chkbx1){
boolean checkstatus;
checkstatus=chkbx1.isSelected();
if (checkstatus==true){
    System.out.println("Checkbox is already checked");  
}
else
{
    chkbx1.click();
    System.out.println("Checked the checkbox");
}
}

//Unchecking 
public void UnCheckingChkbox(WebElement chkbx1){
boolean checkstatus;
checkstatus=chkbx1.isSelected();
if (checkstatus==true) {
chkbx1.click();
     System.out.println("Checkbox is unchecked");
}
else
{
     System.out.println("Checkbox is already unchecked"); 
}
}
```

http://seleniumcodes.blogspot.in/2011/10/checking-and-unchecking-checkbox.html

Comment: thanks @  coder hawk.<input id="role_checkbox_1" class="checkboxtreeHTMLCheckBox" type="checkbox" value="unchecked"/>.using this html code ,tell me how to use.